# Qt5.4 build on Windows, webkit based project

Tags: windows, qt, deployment, build, qwebview

I would like to deploy my Qt project on Windows. The project uses the QWebView control. After compiling the Qt library with the -static flag I tried to build my project and the following error message appeared:

```
Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets webkit
```

How can I solve this problem? Is it possible to deploy an application that uses the QWebView control?

Comment: It is possible, but it doesn't seem like webkit was configured into your Qt build. https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/BuildingQtOnWindows